# Whenever I try to join a zoom meeting for a certain class, it always shows as not started even if it has started

Tags: zoom.us

Whenever I try to join a certain class, it shows as not started even when it is. It is usually fixed by exiting then joining again. However this time it did not work. My teacher has sent me a new link before but it still wont work. Is this a client issue or is the host at fault?